# will the retained/strong class member variables got automatically clean'd up on unloading a view controller?

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

I have the following property

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *cache;
```

.m

```
@synthesize cache = _cache;
```

The data of the `_cache` got built on on viewDidLoad. Now I wonder if `_cache` will be automatically get clean'd up once the view controller is getting unloaded, or do I have to explicitly do a `_cache = nil;` in `viewWillUnload`?

Comment: You say "clean'd up once the view controller is getting unloaded" and then talk about `viewWillUnload`. Maybe that was a typo, and maybe you meant "once the view is getting unloaded", but to be clear, `viewWillUnload` is called when the view is being removed due to low memory but the controller is _not._ So, not only will `viewWillUnload` not empty your cache, but more to the point, you really should really do so yourself in that method (that's the entire purpose of the method). Do this in `viewWillUnload`, `viewDidUnload`, or even better, `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. Jody was spot on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whether you are using ARC or not, they will *not* be cleaned up in `-viewDidUnload`. You have to explicitly release them (or set them to `nil` under ARC.)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO.  Instance variables will not be automatically released.  It does not cause a dealloc on the view controller.  The view being controlled is cleared.

Anything you want cleared, must be done explicitly in viewDidUnload (note that variables added via IB will be automatically placed in that method).

The typical scenario for viewDidUnload is that a view managed by a controller is no longer on the screen (e.g., another controller has pushed with navigation controller).  The system has detected memory pressure, and your view has been unloaded.

Any weak references to objects in your view will be automatically cleared (as long as you don't have extra strong references to them somewhere).  In viewDidUnload, you need to nil strong references to data that can be reloaded when the view is represented on screen.

Executing viewDidUnload is NOT the same as dealloc.  If you are managing resources that must be released (or registered with KVO or Notification Center) you will need to do that work as well.  Note, in these cases you will have to do them both in viewDidUnload and in dealloc (as appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

Can not answer for ARC, but viewdidUnload does not mean the VC is released. It means the view is being released. To force it, you can try having a NavigationController, push a couple of views, and in Simulator send some Memory Warnings. viewDidUnload will be called for the vcs that are not the top one.

Re: ARC, you can surely have a dealloc method, that will be called when the vc is released. Simply don't call super.

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
-(void)dealloc { 
    // If you are using ARC remove the line below
    [super dealloc]
}
```

And put a breakpoint and it will tell you when it is being released.  The dealloc method will be called with ARC as well, just be sure that you don't call [super dealloc] in ARC.

Comment: Huh?  Putting a breakpoint in dealloc will work, but the given code will **not** compile under ARC rules.

Comment: Under ARC remove [super dealloc].  Dealloc is still called with ARC, you are just not allowed to call it yourself.

Comment: @Inturbidus, no offense, but -1 because (a) the answer suggests `[super dealloc]` "will work with ARC as well"; and (b) your answer might lead someone to mistakenly conclude that in typical view lifecycle `viewDidUnload` will be called before `dealloc`, when in fact it's generally not called at all, it's only called in low memory situations, it's called when view is being released but the controller is _not_, and thus trying to draw conclusions of `viewDidUnload` behavior on the basis of controller's `dealloc` may not be illuminating. Happy to change vote if these two issues are addressed.

Comment: I removed my -1, but I still fear that this answer perpetuates the misconception that `dealloc` of a controller has something to do with `viewWillUnload` of the view, which it doesn't. In fact, if one is called, the other isn't! I don't know what a breakpoint in `dealloc` would tell you. Jody's answer sums it up nicely.

Comment: It was simply a tip for his debugging purposes.  Thanks for clearing up the confusion.