# when a view controller is doing viewDidUnload, does it mean that it's getting released?

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [will the retained/strong class member variables got automatically clean'd up on unloading a view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875145/will-the-retained-strong-class-member-variables-got-automatically-cleand-up-on)

As the question shows, when the viewDidUnload is getting called, does it mean that the view controller is getting released? if that's the case, does it mean that all the member variables  (specifically the strong ones) that's allocated within the view controller will get released automatically?